# AngularJS extract JSON Object

Tags: json, angularjs

I downloading JSON data from an address by code:

```
  return {
        all: function () {

         // var dfd = $q.defer();
           var promise =  $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/mobile/").then(function (response) {
             console.log(response.data.hits);

             return response.data;
           });
          // Return the promise to the controller


          return promise;

        }
}
```

Console log returns array of Objects:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

Any open of the object gives:

```
0: Object
   $$hashKey: "object:20"
   _id: "AVCZPOdoX5ZoBStgqx-J"
   _index: "fb_events"
   _score: 1
   _source: Object
   _type: "event"
   __proto__: Object
```

As with the console log level I can get to the field `_id`?

Edit:

He wants to put the data into an array so as to have access to them through another loop which will return me an interesting record. Like:

```
get: function(chatId) {
          for (var i = 0; i < chats.length; i++) {
            if (chats[i].id === parseInt(chatId)) {
              return chats[i];
            }
          }
          return null;
        }
```

Comment: What's your question again? Can you re-write?

Comment: var result = [Object, Object, Object]       var id = result[0]._id;

Comment: I want to show `_id` field like response.data.hits._id, but is does not work

Comment: As your log shows, response.data.hits is a **array** containing 19 objects. That **array** doesn't have any _id field. Each of the 19 objects in the array probably has one: response.data.hits[0]._id, esponse.data.hits[1]._id, etc.

Comment: Try this  -  response.data.hits[0]._id or whatever index you need response.data.hits[i]._id for example if in for loop?

Comment: `response.data.hits[0]._id` it works but i should do it in for lop

Comment: If you need to parse all the data then yes... Ill add a proper answer

Comment: @lukassz then use a for loop. What have you tried? WHat's the problem?

Comment: I'm assuming he just wants to know he's got access to the correct data at this stage?

Comment: He wants to put the data into an array so as to have access to them through another loop which will return me an interesting record. Like:  `get: function(chatId) {
          for (var i = 0; i < chats.length; i++) {
            if (chats[i].id === parseInt(chatId)) {
              return chats[i];
            }
          }
          return null;
        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go following comments...

**EDITED**

```
var chats = []; // global in this instance

var promise =  $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/mobile/")
.then(function (response) {
   console.log(response.data.hits);
   for(var i=0; i < response.data.hits.length; i++)
   {
    console.log(response.data.hits[i]._id);
   }

   chats = response.data.hits; // assign hits[] to chats

   return response.data;
 });

if(chats.length !== 0)
  // do something
```

Comment: Ok, it works. How to assign the response.data to a global array so that it is available for other functions?

Comment: That would depend on your current architecture mate? You could just define a global var and when the promise returns, assign the data to the global variable? You would have to check it has been assigned first though, will update my answer